# SQLiteOpenHelper.onUpgrade how does it exactly works? (app with multiple databases)

Tags: android, sqlite

Google documentation [for SQLiteOpenHelper.onUpgrade](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onUpgrade%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20int,%20int%29) is very general. I'm wondering how onUpgrade execution exactly works?

Does Android stores database version number inside database itself (I tried to find it using database tool aSQLiteManager, btw very good piece of software, but it seems to be hidden if exist)? Or does Android just compares the old and new version of app in the moment of installation and basing on this it definieds old and new version as parameters of onUpgrade.

Let's take an example. I have app verson 1 which can work with multiple databases. At the beginning I have only database A version 1. Next I upgrade app to version 2 and database A is also upgraded to version 2 (onUpgrade is executed). Next I get database B from my friend created by the same app but in version 1 (thus B has also version 1). I copy it to the appropriate dir and run my app. Will onUpgrade method be executed then (for database B version 1, no app reinstallation)?

Answer (score 2):

If you want, you may want to use SQLiteDabase (the first parameter of onUpgrade), with the method getPath to know which databse will be updated.

When you will ask SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase (or getReadableDatabase()), it will be updated if the version you set in constructor is greater than the current version of the database.

If you need different upgrade statements for different databases (which is generally the case), you may want to declare two classes extending SQLiteOpenHelper.

Comment: The version is not(!) stored in android_metadata. Only locale. That's why I was a bit suprising as I expected to find it there.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Just edited my post to not let wrong informations on it. Sorry for this mistake.